# SwiftUI & Distant Child View Dependency Injection

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, swiftui

I am trying to understand how I can inject dependencies into child views using SwiftUI.

For example, if I have a view -

```
struct FeedListView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private(set) var viewModel: FeedViewModel
    @State private var items: [Post] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                ForEach(items, id: \.id) { item in
                    FeedListItemView(viewModel: .init(item: item))
                }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: onLoad)
        .padding()
    }
}

private extension FeedListView {
    
    func onLoad() {
        viewModel.onFeedLoad = { self.items = $0 }
        viewModel.loadFeed()
    }
}
```

with a view model -

```
final class FeedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    typealias LoaderResult = Result<[Post], Error>
    typealias LoaderCompletion = (LoaderResult) -> Void
    typealias Loader = ((@escaping LoaderCompletion) -> Void)
    
    typealias Observer<T> = (T) -> Void
     
    @Published var onFeedLoad: Observer<[Post]>?
    @Published var onLoadingStateChange: Observer<Bool>?

    private let loader: Loader
    
    init(loader: @escaping Loader) {
        self.loader = loader
    }
    
    func loadFeed() {
        onLoadingStateChange?(true)
        loader { [weak self] result in
            if let feed = try? result.get() {
                self?.onFeedLoad?(feed)
            }
            self?.onLoadingStateChange?(false)
        }
    }
}
```

As this is the top level view, I can inject FeedViewModel with it's dependencies at the point of composition.

However this view renders FeedListItemView - that view has it's own view model and will have it's own dependencies.

```
final class FeedListItemViewModel: ObservableObject {
        
    private let item: Post
    
    init(item: Post) {
        self.item = item
    }
    
    func loadImage() {
        let imageURL = item.imageURL
        // do something here to load an image
    }
}

struct FeedListItemView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private(set) var viewModel: FeedListItemViewModel

    init(viewModel: FeedListItemViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("My Awesome Post")
            .onAppear(perform: viewModel.loadImage)
    }
}
```

How can I make an image loader, such as `(_imageURL: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error>` available in FeedListItemViewModel without passing this into FeedListView and then passing it directly to the child views view model?

Testability is very important so I'd like to avoid a singleton instance of dependencies and I'd also like to avoid passing a bunch of values to a view, only for that view to pass them to a child, which in turn passes them to another distant child.

I'd really appreciate any thoughts on how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @EnvironmentObject wrapper to distribute the view model from the ancestor view to its child and grandchild views.

If you instantiate the FeedListView in your app file, add this modifier:

```
.environmentObject(YourViewModel())
```

After you instantiate it in the upmost view, you can use @EnvironmentObject wrapper to access the environment object.

```
@EnvironmentObject var yourVM: YourViewModel
```

However, environment objects are created only once and they work similar to singletons. When you make a change in any of the views, other views see the changed object.

Comment: hmmm, thanks for your input, just to be clear if `FeedListItemViewModel` has a dependency it requires, that dependency is shared between all list items? In that case if I have 5 list items that all try to load a different image, they would use the same image loader instance? I'm not sure that would work would it?

Comment: I am not an expert on dependency injections but since we initiate the view model in the environment only once I believe they all share the same view model object. There is only one view model object in the environment.